# How to make sure a specific pattern is always followed by a specific pattern?

Tags: regex

I need to make sure that every occurrence of `name` is always followed by a specific pattern e.g. `:[a-zA-Z]`. The regular expressions must only match if there is no occurrence of name not followed by this pattern. So the following string must not match because of `Ch%ristoph`.

```
{name:Anton,age:10}{name:Bert,age:20}{name:Ch%ristoph,age:30}
```

To be clear: I need this done **entirely with a regular expression** without using reg ex defines or any other code. (I know about look-arounds and advanced regular expressions but was not able to find a solution for this problem.)

Comment: To do something like this, you would use a lookahead/lookbehind, collectively known as lookaround. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your requirement. Is your condition a pass/fail on the entire input? Or are you trying to capture individual matches? Also, is your example input missing a comma between the 2nd and 3rd brace pairs, or do you need to account for possible missing commas?

Comment: The missing comma was a typo. I need to pass or fail the entire input. It is basically a test. I don't need to capture anything. The regular expression I am using is much more complex. I tried to reduce the problem to the minimum required complexity.

Comment: I removed commas from my example, to simplify the answer because the commas are not part of the core question.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Someone's in a huff?

Answer (score 1):

If you invert the condition, you can easily check whether the string is **invalid** (that is, match on the invalid condition):

```js
var strings = ['{name:Anton,age:10},{name:Bert,age:20},{name:Ch%ristoph,age:30}','{name:Anton,age:10},{name:Bert,age:20}{name:Christoph,age:30}'];
for(var i=0; i<strings.length; i++){
  var match = strings[i].match(/[{,][\s]*name:[a-z]*[^},a-z]/i);
  console.log(strings[i]+' is '+(match==null?'valid':'invalid'))
}
```

If you really need a regex-only solution that passes/fails the string, try something like this:

```js
var strings = ['{name:Anton,age:10},{name:Bert,age:20},{name:Ch%ristoph,age:30}','{name:Anton,age:10},{name:Bert,age:20}{name:Christoph,age:30}'];
for(var i=0; i<strings.length; i++){
  var match = strings[i].match(/^({name:[a-z]+,[^}]+},?)+$/gi);
  console.log(strings[i]+' '+(match==null?'does not match':'matches'))
}
```

Comment: Dude, the for-loop is just an example of usage...you don't have to loop to use the regex. I looped to show the results of the regex when applied to a valid string and an invalid string.

Comment: @mrplow I'm not sure coding is for you.

Comment: No, because you're rejecting perfectly valid answers without demonstrating any comprehension whatsoever. You could make a decent living as a Phlebotomist. https://collegegrad.com/careers/phlebotomists

Comment: You must be using a different flavor of regex, because they do work in Javascript. Where are you testing these?

Comment: "I explicitly said I need this done with a regular expression."  Lol, these ARE regular expressions. Do you know what that means?

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match your exact pattern, which requires only a-z or A-Z after the `name:` portion.

```
name:[a-zA-Z]+,age:[0-9]+
```

You can test it out here. http://regexr.com/3eell

If the requirement is a pass/fail on the entire input, then you could use the following

```
({name:[a-zA-Z]+,age:[0-9]+},?)+
```

And ensure there is one match, and that one match's length is the same as your input length.

Comment: This does not work unfortunately and additionally does not satisfy the requirement of being a reg ex only solution.

Comment: "does not satisfy the requirement of being a reg ex only solution.", which was added *after* I already posted my answer, by the way. Even my edit was posted before that addition, and it does "consume the complete string" also.

Comment: The original question only mentioned regular expressions and regex was the only tag. I had assumed that it was clear that I needed reg ex only solution. Your answer states that I need to ensure that string lengths are equal. Imo this requires additional code. Also your regular expression does not work for me See: https://regex101.com/r/8228Xu/1 Christopher contains an illlegal character but the expression matches anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer myself:

```
^(?:{name:[a-zA-Z]+?,age:\d+})+$
```

Generally speaking: Let α (here `name:`) be the pattern that is always to be followed by pattern β (here `[a-zA-Z]`) . And let , be the delimiter in a structure that is repeated and itself delimited by curly braces. Let ɣ be other patterns inside that structure (here `age:\d+`) Then the regular expression would be:

^(?:{αβ+?,ɣ})+$

I think the key here is to consume the complete string. This is not the case with the previous answers.

Comment: "I think the key here is to consume the complete string. This is not the case with the previous answers."  Other than my edited answer last night, but cool I'm glad you found something that works for you on your own.

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question. Mine does. Why are you downvoting?

Comment: If you mean my answer doesn't work for your homework assignment, fine. But if you run the snippets on my answer you will find that they do exactly what you needed done.

Comment: Please stop claiming this is a homework assigment. Firstly it is not, secondly you are being needlessly condescending, thirdly you are putting yourself in a bad light because all you do is arguing "ad hominem". Also see my comment to your answer, your code works after all.